# SQL Reporting server dataset display data in query window but not display in preview or reporting server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a dataset does use Union to combine two sets of data. All the fields display well on the dataset query window but the first set before Union won't display either on the preview or when the report is deployed line. What's the reason?

And in another report

both parts of Union display but not follow the order by

Thank you

First Part

union

Second Part

ORDER BY ChkDateYearMonth

Answer (score 0):

Try UNION ALL: it may be that the results are identical and UNION will remove duplicate lines. Alternatively, in each query add a new static field like `'Database1' AS [DataSource]` in the first part and `'Database2' AS [DataSource]` in the 2nd part.

If your data is coming from different servers, maybe you have one "Data Source" defined in the report, but only the bottom part of your query pulls from that source? For example, if you have two SQL Servers, SQL1 and SQL2, your UNION query would need to use SQL2 as a "linked server" on SQL1:

```
SELECT [stuff]
FROM Database1.dbo.StuffTable
UNION ALL
SELECT [stuff]
FROM SQL2.Database1.dbo.StuffTable
```

Since SQL2 is a linked server on SQL1, a query run on SQL1 can pull data from SQL2. I hope that makes sense. I doubt that is the problem because it would probably throw an error when you tried to save it.

Can you post your query, or at least some of it so we can get a better look at what you're trying to do?